# Why UIButton.addTarget needs a ":" after the string representing the action?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift, uikit

I have the following code:

`button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonIsPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)`

Why do I need the ":" after the string for action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It comes from Objective-C. Basically it means that the action method takes a parameter. In your case the parameter passed will be the `sender` (i.e. the `UIButton` that generated the action to be called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this some kind os pattern when developing for Apple? Can I find that pattern in other situations?

Comment: Here you are just using the common oop _target action_ pattern. The `:` is just a legacy from Objective-C _messaging_ syntax. UIKit is an all Objective-C framework. You can just have a look to a very basic intro to Objective-C (kind of _hello world tutorial_) to see what kind of syntax you are _passing_.

Comment: Thanks Matteo, I'll seek for more basics on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

because your function buttonIsPressed has 1 parameter. 
one :  equal to one parameter

Answer (score 0):

U dont need it. But then you have to have function that takes no parameters.

```
func buttonIsPressed(){
    println("button pressed")
}
```